# Adjust the camera view actually separate all my objects

Tags: objects, transforms, camera

I would like to adjust the camera view, so I press the <kbd>Ctrk</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> to switch to the camera view window, then I try to adjust the camera window.

[image: this is the screen shot before I try to adjust the camera view]

Then, I press the <kbd>G</kbd> key, and try to move the view window up or down, but finally, I see that all the objects were moved, not the camera view itself:

[image: all the objects were moved and they get separated]

What causes this behavior?

BTW: I have just tried a very simple blender file (which only contains the default Cube, and I can correctly move the camera view), so are there some settings wrong in my first case? Thanks.

**Edit:** [test blend file](http://pan.baidu.com/s/1c0xN6Ru)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You had "proportional editing object mode" enabled. Toggle it off and it should work as expected.

[image]

Comment: Dear user2859, thanks, this did fix my issue. I found that this option my be enabled by hitting the O key by accident.