# Scaling a Cylinder scales other layers too?

Tags: shape-keys

So I'm following this tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CVPcT0dJmoY

And at 43 Minutes in, he's putting a cylinder into the ground. I try to replicate this, but scaling or moving the cylinder also scales and moves the ground layer. I made a video explaining my situation:

https://youtu.be/9P0pyaOD78k

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: all the same issue: [Why is an object stuck to another?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1765/2217), [Adjust the camera view actually separate all my objects](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/7917/2217), [Strange problem: can't transform faces, edges, or vertices without transforming the whole object!](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/27394/2217), [Change height of an inset extrusion](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/18797/2217)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have *proportional editing* turned on. When both objects are within the influence radius, (the white circle around your mouse) the objects will be affected. Pressing <kbd>O</kbd> (the letter O, not zero) toggles this on or off.